# Give cloud function a unique uid?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-security

Is there any way to provide a cloud function with a unique uid so it can be constrained by Realtime Database rules?

I was unable to find any information about this via Google and Stack says I need more text.

Comment: You will have to initialize the admin sdk to be scoped to a particular UID, as shown in the dup, then only use that initialized instances of the SDK to access the database.

Comment: Thank you, Doug!